Complex functions that cannot be plotted
My college professor of complex calculus, mentioned that there is a point that some complex functions can no longer be seen or graphed and that in order to see them, we have to take their image out of the graph.

What is your question?

What does it mean to "take the image of a complex function out of the graph"? That sentence makes no mathematical sense to me.

Do you guys have Turrets?

I bet your professor is referring to Riemann surfaces. Some complex functions are mutli-valued, eg. $\log(z)$. To visualize the behavior of $\log(z)$ across a branch cut, it do make sense to view the image out of the plane.  As an example, look at picture of $\log(z)$ in above wiki ref.

The graph of most complex functions obviously live in $\mathbb C^2$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$. So the problems in graphing them should be obvious.

Well, functions from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C,$ or what amounts to $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2,$ can't be visualized very well,  since the graphs are essentially $4$-dimensional. The Riemann-zeta function is a perfect example,  though there are plenty of others.
There's techniques though for getting a look at them, like taking "slices".
